# Variable undefined error on ActiveX checkbox when workbook closes

Tags: vba, excel, activex

I am developing data editing tool in Excel VBA. On one of the worksheets there is an ActiveX combobox which is used to select a data row. The change event on the combobox updates a series of ActiveX checkboxes based on the data in the selected row.

This appears to be functioning correctly except for one aspect. Sometimes when the Excel workbook is closed the act of closing triggers the checkbox_change event. At this point the compiler checks that all the variables in the method are defined and finds that the checkboxes no longer exist, giving a "Compile error: Variable undefined" message.

Changing worksheets, which triggers worksheet_activate event (that updates some properties of a user form) seems to be what controls whether the error occurs or not.

Using the object browser during the debug I can see that the checkboxes are not listed, whereas they are under normal execution. The call stack at the point that the error occurs includes only the checkbox_change event.

I have tried a (somewhat overkill) solution of including 'Exit Sub' at the begging of the event handler, but it has no effect - VBA still wants to know about the presently undefined variable.

Any advice on how to intercept this issue or prevent it would be greatly appreciated.

This is a from-scratch example which I believe has all the elements of the workbook where I'm getting the error, but the error is not occurring in this example - I do not know which aspect of the problem is missing. Hopefully this is helpful.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    ' apply the checkbox value to the spreadsheet
    Dim rows As Range
    Set rows = Sheet1.Range("RowIDs")

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rows

        If cell.Value = ComboBox1.Value Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = CheckBox1.Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    ' get the value from the spreadsheet
    ' apply it to the checkbox
    Dim rows As Range
    Set rows = Sheet1.Range("RowIDs")

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rows
        If cell.Value = ComboBox1.Value Then
            CheckBox1.Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value  '<<< This would be the line that causes the error
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    populateCombo
End Sub

Private Sub populateCombo()
    Dim rows As Range
    Set rows = Sheet1.Range("RowIDs")
    ComboBox1.Clear

    ComboBox1.Text = "--- Select row to activate ---"

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In rows
       ComboBox1.AddItem cell.Value
       Next cell
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = Sheet1.Name
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

[This is a screenshot of the worksheet where the controls live](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks7T2.png)

Comment: Seeing the code for that handler would probably help us help you there. I have an idea of what the problem (and solution) could be, but I need to assume way too many things and that's a waste of time for both you and me. Please [edit] your question to include a proper [mcve].

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I have recreated a simple example that should have all the elements of the problem, but it's not triggering the error - don't know why. I will post that in case it helps you.

Comment: The `Variable Undefined` error makes me suspect there is some variable that you are using that has not been declared. I don't see this occurring in your example code; but with the `Option Explicit` maybe check that all variables are `Dim`'d before use? Does you code compile without error when you click the Complie VBAProject option from the Debug Menu?

Comment: @ArcherBird Thanks for taking a look. It happily compiles with no issues when we do debug->compile prior to execution. I really seems like the issue is that in the process of shutting down, excel has removed the checkboxes from memory before triggering the combobox change event, so at that point the checkboxes are undeclared. It's very intermittent. I could reproduce it in my production version at will yesterday, but today the same steps are not throwing the error.

Comment: Very strange indeed. I guess, you just have to figure out and trace every event that would be kicked off by the workbook closing. That looks like this by the way: 

1)Workbook_BeforeClose
2)Workbook_BeforeSave
3)Workbook_AfterSave
4)Workbook_WindowDeactivate
5)Workbook_Deactivate

See if there is code in any of those events that would trigger checkbox events. You would have to be on the look out for any code that would trigger any other type of event too and follow the events rabbit trail :-(

Comment: @ArcherBird That was a useful comment. I think I've worked out why the error is now not happening. We had put a handler on the workbook_beforeClose event to ensure that only users with the correct access level can save the workbook. With that handler in place the error doesn't fire. It may be because it's now closing only the workbook, and not the whole excel app. It feels more a workaround than a fix, but I'll aim to submit that as an answer when I get more time.